# JQuery .html() working in IE but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I have a div with `id=slRecipelList` and a text box with id= txtRecipesWk1 containing a HTML string. I want to copy the HTML string from the text box to the div, here is my code:

```
    $('#slRecipelList').html($('#txtRecipesWk1').val());
```

The code works fine in IE (V 8) but not in Firefox (V 3.6.18), when I step through the code and do `console.log($('#slRecipelList').html())`, it returns null.

I’ve also tried append (after emptying the div) with same result – okay in IE, not working in Firefox.

Am I missing something obvious or silly here?

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.com demo that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/xyJVK/

Comment: Figured it out. Nothing to do with my code, it was a problem with some HTML comments in the page. I had extra dashes which screw up in Firefox so Firefox wasn't even seeing the div  ... some days I hate computers, grrrrrr. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your HTML comments, they might be giving you problems.

Comment: I forgot to make this a community wiki, but you should accept the answer so 1) it doesn't show as unanswered anymore, and 2) so other people will be able to find the solution to a similar problem.